# Composing Action(BodyParser) with ActionFilter in play framework scala

Tags: scala, function, playframework, playframework-2.0, function-composition

I've got a play framework application and a problematic action. I'm trying to parse a request body using `parse.form` and then have an `ActionFilter` run against that parsed body.

So far I've got something like this

```
object ModelValidationAction extends ActionFilter[Request[MyModel]]{
  def filter[A <: MyModel](request: Request[A]) = ???
}

def routePointsHere = (Action(parse.form(myModelForm)) andThen ModelValidationAction) { (request: Request[MyModel]) => ??? }
```

however IDEA gives me the error hint

> expected Action[MyModel] => NotInferredA, actual ModelValidationAction.type

and the compiler tells me

> ... missing argument list for method apply in trait ActionBuilder
>   [error] Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
>   [error] You can make this conversion explicit by writing `apply _` or `apply(_)(_)` instead of `apply`.

So I can gather that the issue is the method `apply[A](bodyParser: BodyParser[A])(block: R[A] => Result): Action[A]` around the fact that that second parameter list is not getting filled, but I don't know exactly how the language behaves here.

My (completely baseless) assumption is that `Action(parse.form(myModelForm))` would become `Request[MyModel] => Result` and that invoking `andThen` would return the same.

Any pointers as to what I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: I had a very similar issue, except I wanted to do async. For that the solution is something like: `Action.andThen(ModelValidationAction).async(parse.json) { ??? }`. I expect it'd be very similar here too, but I'm not sure exactly how it'd map.